# Facebook login button blocks whole android activity

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I work on a facebook connect integration, I work on this tutorial :
 - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0 
It's working well : I get a connection, but since I have integrated the button in my activity, the rest of the activity stoped working. No interaction is possible in the rest of the activity.

In my main activity in the `onCreate` I have this code:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    } else {

        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
                .commit();

    }
```

I think it's the Fragment witch causes this issue, even if I am not very confortable dealing with fragments.
My activity is a fragment activity and MainFragment extends fragment.

I read a lot of topic's but I didn't found any answers to solve my problem. 
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: you can remove that code if there is no use of that code..

Comment: Sounds like you are somehow blocking your main thread.. are you doing any networking or other more expensive tasks in your main thread? Remember proper use of e.g. AsyncTasks or simply additional threads.

Comment: Do you have to use fragments?

Comment: I don't have any heavy tasks to run. Facebook's tutorial show this code as an exemple to use its login button. I don't have any idea how to do it otherwise.
But I currently need this code to implement the button. This part is working and show a Log In or Log Out button depending on the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use an other tutorial and it's work see below :

http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example